# Show only one hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I'm hidding 2 divs and I want to make that it would be shown only one of them in same time.

For example if I click on first - it shows up. Then I click on second and then first hides and show only the second div.

```
<div id="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;"><ul><li>Button1</li><li>Button2</li><li>Button3</li></ul></div>

<br><br>

<div id="showmenu2">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu2" style="display: none;"><ul><li>Button1</li><li>Button2</li><li>Button3</li></ul></div>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showmenu').click(function() {
                $('.menu').toggle("slide");
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
                $('.menu2').toggle("slide");
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/APA2S/3337/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kriyeta/APA2S/3343/

Comment: Your code is not really maintenable. What happen if you have let's say a menu with ten elements? You should wrap it in common container and/or using some common classes, not IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $('.menu').toggle("slide");
        $('.menu2').hide("slide");//hide the menu2 when the menu is clicked
    });

    $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
        $('.menu2').toggle("slide");
        $('.menu').hide("slide");//hide the menu when the menu2 is clicked
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/APA2S/3338/

Comment: @Xinel please click on the tick to mark your question as resolved

Comment: Surely! It didn't allow to mark it, I had to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $('.menu').slideDown();
        $('.menu2').slideUp();
    });

    $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
        $('.menu2').slideDown();
        $('.menu').slideUp();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu, .menu2').stop().slideUp();
            $('.menu').stop().toggle("slideDown");
    });

    $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
            $('.menu, .menu2').stop().slideUp();
            $('.menu2').stop().toggle("slideDown");
    });
});
```

Avoid repeating $(document).ready,
I also fix your animations ...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/APA2S/3344/

Answer (score 1):

please replace following script it will work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu').toggle("slide");
            $('.menu2').hide("slide");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
            $('.menu2').toggle("slide");
            $('.menu').hide("slide");
    });
});
```

Comment: I know dear @suchit but main thing in this hide and show so i just give soluation for that

Comment: when you are posting try to post in proper way that is all i mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $('.hidden').hide();
            $('.menu').toggle("slide");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
        $('.hidden').hide();
        $('.menu2').toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/APA2S/3341/)
dont forget to add hidden class to your menus
you can use that code if you have more than 2 menus

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:use simply `hide()` you will get it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu2').click(function() {
                  $('.menu').hide();
                $('.menu2').toggle("slide");

        });

            $('#showmenu').click(function() {
                  $('.menu2').hide();
                $('.menu').toggle("slide");

        });
});
```